# How to sort UTF-8 lines in Vim?

Tags: vim, unicode, utf-8

I have these lines in Vim:

```
a
c
b
e
é
f
g
```

and when I do `:%sort`, I get this:

```
a
b
c
e
f
g
é
```

Obviously, the "é" line should not be at the end, it should be after the "e" line. Is it possible to get Vim to sort these lines correctly? Not using the ASCCI key for the characters but the actual character.

I also tried with `:!sort` (to use GNU `sort` utiliy) but I get the same result.

Comment: It's not as obvious as you think it is. The exact ordering depends a lot on the locale. My guess is that the local you use isn't the one you want to use. What does the command `locale` print on your system?

Answer (score 5):

`:%sort` and `:%!sort` do not necessarily work in the same way.  To quote `:help sort`:

> The details about sorting depend on
>   the library function used.  There is
>   no guarantee that sorting is "stable"
>   or obeys the current locale.  You will
>   have to try it out.

On the other hand, GNU sort sorts according to the current locale.  To quote `man sort`:

> ***  WARNING  ***  The locale specified by the environment affects
>   sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses
>   native byte values.

On my system (Ubuntu 9.10 with fr_CA.UTF-8 temporarily set) `:%sort` sorts as if `C` or `POSIX` was set, while `:%!sort` sorts according to the French locale.

My guess is that you've initially tried both `:%sort` and `:%!sort` under a POSIX-like locale (which yielded the same result), and then continued your experiments with different locales using `:%sort` only (which always returned POSIX-like order).  Can you confirm that?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification between `:%sort` and `:%!sort` in terms of locale. However, even with `LC_ALL` set to `fr_CA.UTF-8`, the `:%!sort` command still incorrectly sort the lines. The problem is probably not related to Vim, as running `sort` on a file in a regular terminal doesn't work correctly either. I'm on a Mac so that might be the problem. I'll look into that.

Comment: That's strange...  You're right that it's better to focus on GNU sort first, as the problem doesn't look to be vim-specific.  I don't have access to a Mac right now, so I can't help you, but I've found this: http://discussions.info.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=11129073  Maybe that discussion is somehow relevant.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I get the following using `:%!sort`:

```
a
b
c
e
é
f
g
```

which is what is supposed to happen. It seems like your locale set up might be to blame. I'm not sure what exactly is wrong, but FWIW, I have the following environment setting: `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8`

Comment: Same here.  I'm on Ubuntu 9.04 with `sort` 6.10.

Comment: That’s weird, I have `LANG=fr_CA.UTF-8` and `LC_ALL=fr_CA.UTF-8`.