# sort in vim vs. external sort

Tags: linux, sorting, vim

I found a problem of sorting in vim: the sorting result inside vim is different from the result in terminal.

For example, I have a file `test.txt`

```
中国
美国
```

Both the command `:sort` and `%!sort` in vim result in

```
中国
美国
```

which is a wrong alphabetical order. But the command `sort test.txt` in terminal leads to the correct one

```
美国
中国
```

The locale in both my terminal and vim are `en_US.UTF-8`, so what is the reason?

Although there is a similar question [How to sort UTF-8 lines in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683132/how-to-sort-utf-8-lines-in-vim),

However, I want to figure out why `:%!sort` is different from `sort test.txt`, while the `:!locale` is the same with `locale`. And how to reproduce the vim's behavior in terminal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort UTF-8 lines in Vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683132/how-to-sort-utf-8-lines-in-vim)

Comment: Similar question, but not solved. I just want to figure out why `:%!sort` is different from `sort` given the same locale, and how to reproduce the result of `:%!sort` in the terminal.

Comment: Run `:!env` and see what `LC_COLLATE` is defined as when running a command from vim. It maybe different than when you run it from a terminal where you do the `sort test.txt` directly.

Comment: @KurtStutsman There is no such env variable, only LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Your locale is not set for whatever language your file is in. Why would you expect sort to sort it alphabetically?

Comment: @KurtStutsman The text I'm testing is Chinese, which is fully covered by en_US.UTF-8, and it works in terminal with the exactly same env variables.